# How do I set the user of php-fpm to be php-user instead of www-data?

Tags: users, init.d

I am using php-fpm on debian with nginx for php5 support.
I would like to have php-fpm to be under the user&group php-user instead of www-data.

I thought the init.d script would have the user mentioned or uses a file which has www-data written in it. Yet I don't see it. How do I spawn this process to be under user php-user:php-user? Here is the php5-fpm init.d script on my server.

I tried looking at start-stop-daemon man pages but didn't see it. I'm sure this is simple but I don't know how to do it.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          php-fpm php5-fpm
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts php5-fpm
# Description:       Starts PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager Daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Ondrej Sury <ondrej@debian.org>

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager"
NAME=php5-fpm
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf"
PIDFILE=/var/run/php5-fpm.pid
TIMEOUT=30
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function to check the correctness of the config file
#
do_check()
{
    [ "$1" != "no" ] && $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -t 2>&1 | grep -v "\[ERROR\]"
    FPM_ERROR=$($DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -t 2>&1 | grep "\[ERROR\]")

    if [ -n "${FPM_ERROR}" ]; then
    echo "Please fix your configuration file..."
    $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS -t 2>&1 | grep "\[ERROR\]"
    return 1
    fi
    return 0
}

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS 2>/dev/null \
        || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/$TIMEOUT/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_check $VERBOSE
    case "$?" in
        0)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
            2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac
        ;;
        1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
    stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    check)
        do_check yes
    ;;
    reload|force-reload)
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_reload
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
    restart)
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

:
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Look in your conf file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. There you will find options **user** and **group**. It will appear as `[www]`. You can make it into `[myuser] group=mygroup`.

Comment: Can you give me a little more info? `user=thename` gave me an error so i put [worker] above it since a site mention it was a worker object. It still uses www-data however. I see that its an option but i dont see how to set it

Comment: I figured it out. Its actually in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Theres a line that uses www-data in it. Or one may be able to write `[www] group=groupname` at the very end of the file you mentioned

Comment: Yes, as you realized it is in the pool section. I got the config file from your init script. Some distros do it differently and do not use the "./pool.d/" setup. Glad you got it working.

Comment: In my case, on Ubuntu 12.04, there were also options for listen-owner and listen-group which needed to be set as well.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I also had to edit `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php7.0-fpm.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of CentOS, in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
change the definitions of user and group:

```
;default user and group
user = apache
group = apache
```